# Efficient way to convert a compile time known function argument to a std::integral_constant

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Yesterday I read a [blog entry](http://blog.mattbierner.com/stupid-template-tricks-stdintegral_constant-user-defined-literal/)
about converting a compile time known function argument from a constexpr function to a type like `std::integral_constant<>`.

A possible usage example is to convert types from user defined literals.

Consider the following example:

```
constexpr auto convert(int i)
{
    return std::integral_constant<int, i>{};
}

void test()
{
    // should be std::integral_constant<int, 22>
    using type = decltype(convert(22));
}
```

But obviously and as expected Clang throws the following error:

`error: ‘i’ is not a constant expression
     return std::integral_constant<int, i>{};
                                         ^`

The Author of the mentioned blog proposed to use a templated user defined literal to split
the number into a std::integer_sequence to parse it into an int.

But this suggestion seems not useable for me.

**Is there an efficient way to convert a compile time known function argument into a type like `std::integral_constant<>`?**

Comment: How is `using type = decltype(convert(22));` more readable than an alias template (or a variable template)?

Comment: Do you have any reason to doubt the information you got from that blog post, other than wishful thinking? It already explains why this is invalid, and I don't see how an answer here telling you that same thing can improve on that.

Comment: `using type = decltype(convert(22))` was just an example how to extract the type of the given expression. I thought about possibilities to parse the expression `convert(22)` into a compile time AST expression which could be evaluated from other templates without using macros or user defined literals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function *arguments* can **never** be compile-time constants. While this is a design flaw of `constexpr` in my opinion, it is the way it is.

There might be other ways to do what you want (macros, templates), but you can not do it with function arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a template:

```
template <int i>
constexpr auto convert()
{
    return std::integral_constant<int, i>();
}

void test()
{
    // should be std::integral_constant<int, 22>
    using type = decltype(convert<22>());
}
```

Or(even better) you can use template aliases:

```
template <int i> using convert = std::integral_constant<int, i>;
void test()
{
    // should be std::integral_constant<int, 22>
    using type = convert<22>;
}
```