# Convert constexpr compile-string into a template char list

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, constexpr

There is a Scott Schurr's implementation of compile-time strings:

```
class str_const {
    const char* const p_;
    const std::size_t sz_;
public:
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr str_const(const char(&a)[N]) : p_(a), sz_(N-1) {}
    constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n) {
        return n < sz_ ? p_[n] : throw std::out_of_range("");
    }
    constexpr std::size_t size() {
        return sz_;
    }
};
```

This is nice, but I would like to operate on compile-time char lists like `string<'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'>`. *Is there a way to convert `str_const` into such lists?*

The implementation routes I could think of are templates and functions. It's impossible to convert `str_const` into something else via templates, because `str_const` is an invalid type for a non-type template argument. Also it's impossible to define such function, because it would have different return values `string<...>` depending on the value of its argument.

UPD. Editing to get rid of that "your question might be a duplicate" message, because it is obvious from the text of this question that a string is not an integer.

Comment: Related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055791/efficient-way-to-convert-a-compile-time-known-function-argument-to-a-stdintegr

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible.  You can use these constexpr string types in constant expressions.  So like you can pass `str[0]` to a template expecting an integral parameter.

Thus you should be able to create a range template from 0 to `str.size()`.  Then you'd do a recursive instantiation of something that builds an mpl::string with repeated calls to concat.

It would take a while to implement this so I'm not going to provide code right now, but I think the idea is possible.  Here's my string implementation to maybe help.  The code has tests that prove it can be used in the context you are trying to use it in.

https://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/compile-time-strings-with-constexpr/
https://github.com/crazy-eddie/crazycpp/tree/master/20141016-constexprstr

Comment: Yep, that's totally what I ended up doing. Though I cannot figure out how to hide this horrible circuitry into a single macro. I'm sure somebody did this before, and, honestly, I've hoped this question will be marked as a duplicate. Here's a sketch: http://ideone.com/jggupE

Comment: The problem is that I see no way to unpack variadic template inline.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph - You're right.  Now that I think about it I believe I tried this already.  The main problem is that function parameters aren't constexpr.  So THEY can't be used in constant context, even though if you simply return them they can.  So maybe using returns somehow you can create the range as a constant.